# Apache2 Virtual Host Document root for wildcart domain

Tags: ubuntu, server, apache2

```
I have a special situation where i want to setup Document root based on subdomain.
```

my all subdomain has a              keyword  -web for example demo-web.example.com  site2-web.example.com
below is my virtual host but its not        working

```
i want to set the document root like this if domain is 
    demo-web.example.com ->>> /var/www/html/demo-web
    site-web.example.com >>>> /var/www/html/site-web
    *-web.example.com    >>>> /var/www/html/*-web

   <VirtualHost *:80>
       
        ServerName wp.example.com
        
        ServerAlias *-web.example.com
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/html/%1-web

       

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    </VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the directive VirtualDocumentRoot you must first enable mod_vhost_alias.

```
sudo a2enmod vhost_alias && sudo service apache2 restart
```

Now you can implement following VHost:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName wp.example.com
    ServerAlias *.example.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/html/%1/

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Consider you have the three domains:

- wp-example.com
- demo-web.example.com
- site-web.example.com

Then you will need these three directories:

- /var/www/html/wp/
- /var/www/html/demo-web/
- /var/www/html/site-web/